# Doubt on max tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Im trying to understand proof of corollary $11.34$ from [here](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/banelson/conferences/GOALS/notes/7-13_Cstar_notes.pdf). The corollary goes as follows:

> Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras. Given any $C^{\ast}$-norm $\vert \vert . \vert \vert$on $A_1 \otimes A_2$, there is a surjective ${\ast}$-homomorphism, $A_1 \otimes ^{\text{max}} A_2 \to \overline{A_1\otimes A_2}^{\vert \vert .\vert \vert}$ extending the identity map on $A_1 \otimes A_2$.

> Can someone explain me why the identity map $A_1 \otimes A_2 \to \overline{A_1\otimes A_2}^{\vert \vert .\vert \vert}$ is a contraction to extend it to desired space?

Comment: This is trivial. The identity map $A_1 \odot A_2 \to A_1 \odot A_2$ is max-min continuous because the minimal norm is dominated by the maximal norm. Hence, it extends uniquely to a $*$-morphism $A_1 \otimes_{max} A_2 \to A_1 \otimes_{min} A_2$ and it is surjective because the image contains the dense subspace $A_1 \odot A_2$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Thank you. I was basically trying to understand the last line from Proof of Cor. $11.34$. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the notations from *loc. cit.* - and start with $A_1,A_2$ as in *loc. cit.* and a $C^*$-norm $\|\ \cdot\ \|$ on the algebraic tensor product
$B_0:=A_1\odot A_2$. Let $C$ be the completion of $B_0$ w.r.t. this norm, so $(C, \|\ \cdot\ \|)$ is explicitly in that long notation $\left(\overline{A_1\odot A_2}^{\|\ \cdot\ \|}\ ,\ \|\ \cdot\ \|\right)$.

Now on $B_0:=A_1\odot A_2$ we also have the $\max$-norm $\|\ \cdot\ \|_\max$, and the completion w.r.t. this norm is $(B, \|\ \cdot\ \|_\max)=(A_1\otimes_\max A_2, \|\ \cdot\ \|_\max)$.

We define from $(B_0,\|\ \cdot\ \|_\max)$ a map $\pi$ to $(C,\|\ \cdot\ \|)$ by $\pi x = x$. Now we are in the situation of Proposition 11.33. The $*$-algebra $B_0$ is dense in $B$. The map $\pi$ is a $*$-homomorphism. And $\pi$ is a contraction from $(B_0, \|\ \cdot\ \|_\max)$ to $(C,\|\ \cdot\ \|)$
since for any $x\in B_0$ we have
$$
\|\pi x\|_C=\|x\|_C=\|x\|\ {\color{blue}\le}\ \|x\|_\max=\|x\|_B\ .
$$
The blue inequality comes from the claim in the sentence immediately preceding Cor. 11.34.

Comment: In the last line of Proof of Cor.  $11.34$, it's written that "as a surjective ${\ast}$-homomorphism, it's contractive and so $\vert \vert x \vert \vert \leq \vert \vert x \vert \vert_{\text{max}}$ for all $x \in B_0$".  I don't understand why do we need to say this line?

Comment: @MathLover I don't think this is correct. You cannot make this conclusion on the $*$-algebra level (without completeness).

Comment: I was answering the question explicitly stated in the last paragraph in the post. So why is the map $x\to x$ a contraction from $B_0:=A_1\odot A_2$ to its completion w.r.t. the norm $\|\ \|$. Now if we take the same norm on $B_0$, there is nothing to be shown any longer, we have an isomorphism. If we take the $\max$-norm on $B_0$, then we have the one line with the blue inequality. This inequality is extracted from the text in the proposition before. The question about the last line in the proof of Cor. 11.34 ... It seems to be an alternative argument

Comment: @dan_fulea: I understand your argument but I don't follow the last line of the proof.  The main purpose of my question was to understand last line, namely the "alternative argument"(if it's really true).